# Securing jQuery calls to Spring MVC REST API using Spring Security

Tags: ajax, json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a REST JSON API with the Spring MVC Framework. I want to serve a single HTML application to the user and the whole communication between server and client is done with JSON format. So the client single HTML application uses jQuery to send AJAX calls to the server.

My big problem is to find the right way to do integrate a proper security technique. I read a lot about basic, digest or form based authentication via Spring Security, but I don't think this is the right way. I want to get JSON responses if the user isn't logged in and I don't want to send a jsessionid with each request.

Could you please tell me the right way or the best-practice how to authenticate user by performing AJAX requests? Maybe it's OAuth 2-legged? (don't have much clue of OAuth)

Comment: Have u seen this http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/#springsec

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store auth information in server-side session (and use JSESSIONID in cookies/urls) you may send auth info with every ajax request using BASIC auth header (created in JS).

I've never used 2-legged oauth, so I won't comment about it.

edit: typo

Comment: my current insights: because i want to be able to serve my single-page-homepage with json and a ios app, i need two different authentication methods. a form-based login with cookies for the AJAX calls and a Basic-Authentication for the iOS App (both run over HTTPS). I implemented the authentication with Spring Security and multiple request mappings for the same controller. For each controller there is a mapping for (/ajax/controlerName/ and /rest/controlername). Hence, i can setup two different authentication methods for the urls /ajax/** and /rest/**. Is this a good solution?